# Excessive power consumption in suspend mode

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management, battery

When I put my laptop into suspend mode it consumes around half of the battery in around 8 hours. This is pretty higher when comparing the previous versions of Xubuntu that I've used.

Any idea how to track why the consumption so high? I'm not able to install another OS to check the results since this is the only laptop I'm using for work and for my personal things.

Hardware:

```
Asus UX430UN
i7-8550u
16GB Memory
512Gb SSD
```

Software:

```
Xubuntu 18.04 
Linux 4.15.0-24-lowlatency (I've also tried with generic kernel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most probably related to the older kernel. I've upgraded to the latest mainline kernel (4.18) and it seems all the problems related to the suspend mode have been resolved.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the same excessive power draining in suspend mode. Running Ubuntu 18.10, therefore using kernel 4.18.0.
The drain was about 70% in the 7hours I've been away. Here is my syslog across the suspend time, in case that could help our savior: https://pastebin.com/0K7njD9a